# Gibbs free energy as a difference of irreversible and reversible heats

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I read in a book that ∆G=∆H-T∆S and then ∆H and T∆S were substituted with Q and Qrev respectively(where Q and Qrev are heats added to the system in any process and reversible process respectively) and then there were two cases,

- Case 1:irreversible process
  Q was replaced with Qirr(heat added to system irreversibly)so ∆G=Qirr-Qrev
- Case 2:reversible process
  Q was replaced with Qrev and so ∆G=0

What I don't understand is that replacing T∆S with Qrev in both the cases implies that the state change in both cases is same(∆H,∆S and ∆G are state functions) but the values of ∆H and ∆G imply otherwise.Is the book wrong or am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Please provide a reference for your book.

Comment: @ChetMiller R.C. Mukherjee's modern approach to physical chemistry(1) applications of the concept of equilibrium